# Storing a closure with lifetimes in a struct

Tags: rust

I'm trying to store closures in a `Vec` that is part of a struct. The closure is a factory function which receives 2 references as arguments and produces a trait object which stores the references the closure receives as arguments.

Because of that, the produced trait object has a lifetime that must not exceed the lifetime of the references. Also `component_registrations` will be accessed from multiple threads and is therefore wrapped in an `Arc<Mutex>`.

I tried implementing it but the compiler says that the generic parameter `F` of the `register_component` function doesn't satisfy the trait bound used in `component_registrations`.

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::Arc;

pub mod gl {
    pub struct Gl();
}

pub struct ComponentRegistry<'a> {
    gl: &'a gl::Gl
}

pub trait Component<'a> {
}

pub struct Application {
    component_registrations: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Box<for<'b> Fn(&'b ComponentRegistry<'b>, &'b gl::Gl) -> Box<Component<'b>> + Send + 'static>>>>
}

impl Application {
    pub fn new() -> Application {
        Application {
            component_registrations: Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]))
        }
    }

    pub fn register_component<'a, F>(&mut self, register: F) where F: Fn(&'a ComponentRegistry<'a>, &'a gl::Gl) -> Box<Component<'a>> + Send + 'static {
        self.component_registrations.lock().unwrap().push(Box::new(register));
    }
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'b> F: std::ops::Fn<(&'b ComponentRegistry<'b>, &'b gl::Gl)>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:27:59
   |
27 |         self.component_registrations.lock().unwrap().push(Box::new(register));
   |                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `for<'b> std::ops::Fn<(&'b ComponentRegistry<'b>, &'b gl::Gl)>` is not implemented for `F`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where for<'b> F: std::ops::Fn<(&'b ComponentRegistry<'b>, &'b gl::Gl)>` bound
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `for<'b> std::ops::Fn(&'b ComponentRegistry<'b>, &'b gl::Gl) -> std::boxed::Box<Component<'b>> + std::marker::Send`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'b> <F as std::ops::FnOnce<(&'b ComponentRegistry<'b>, &'b gl::Gl)>>::Output == std::boxed::Box<Component<'b>>`
  --> src/main.rs:27:59
   |
27 |         self.component_registrations.lock().unwrap().push(Box::new(register));
   |                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter 'b, found concrete lifetime
   |
note: concrete lifetime that was found is the lifetime 'a as defined on the method body at 26:5
  --> src/main.rs:26:5
   |
26 | /     pub fn register_component<'a, F>(&mut self, register: F) where F: Fn(&'a ComponentRegistry<'a>, &'a gl::Gl) -> Box<Component<'a>> + Send + 'static {
27 | |         self.component_registrations.lock().unwrap().push(Box::new(register));
28 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `for<'b> std::ops::Fn(&'b ComponentRegistry<'b>, &'b gl::Gl) -> std::boxed::Box<Component<'b>> + std::marker::Send`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a higher ranked lifetime when you define your `component_registrations` struct field, you should use a higher ranked lifetime for `F` as well.

Also, if you say `Box<Component<'b>>`, it really means `Box<Component<'b> + 'static>` (so the trait object can contain only owned data). What you really need is `Box<Component<'b> + 'b>`, which means it is a trait object that implements `Component<'b>` and it can also contain borrowed data which live at least as long as `'b`.

The relevant part is

```
pub struct Application {
    component_registrations: Vec<Box<for<'b> Fn(&'b ComponentRegistry<'b>, &'b gl::Gl) -> Box<Component<'b> + 'b> + Send + 'static>>
}

impl Application {
    pub fn register_component<F>(&mut self, register: F) where F: for<'b> Fn(&'b ComponentRegistry<'b>, &'b gl::Gl) -> Box<Component<'b> + 'b> + Send + 'static {
        self.component_registrations.push(Box::new(register));
    }
}
```

You can see the [full example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cf64e0139293a0eeb927aff9238b0395&version=stable). Note, that I removed the `Arc` and `Mutex` types from your example since they were not relevant.

Comment: I did try this already but I wasn't able to call `register_component` then see [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=301547098400e05e9c00f6a8fc883316&version=undefined).

Comment: @xomz I updated the solution to cope with the new error.