# Lifetime of a closure stored in a struct

Tags: rust

I tried to apply the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482957/storing-a-closure-with-lifetimes-in-a-struct) to my situation, but failed to do so.
I assume, what I try to do is much simpler.

Before I explain, first a bit of code:

```rust
type Coord = (usize, usize);

pub struct SquareIterator {
    upper_bounds: Coord,
    direction: Coord,
    predicate: Box<dyn Fn(Coord) -> bool>,
    current: Coord,
}

impl SquareIterator {
    pub fn new<P>(
        start_square: Coord,
        direction: Coord,
        board_size: Coord,
        predicate: P,
    ) -> SquareIterator
    where
        P: Fn(Coord) -> bool,
    {
        SquareIterator {
            upper_bounds: board_size,
            direction,
            predicate: Box::new(predicate),
            current: start_square,
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for SquareIterator {
    type Item = Coord;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let next = (
            self.current.0 + self.direction.0,
            self.current.1 + self.direction.1,
        );
        if next.0 >= self.upper_bounds.0 || next.1 >= self.upper_bounds.1 {
            None
        } else if (self.predicate)(next) {
            self.current = next;
            Some(self.current)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

It is about the predicate closure, which is supposed to live as long as the containing struct `SquareIterator` lives.

Application code, using this looks along the lines of:

```rust
struct Board {
    // ... some members ...
}
impl Board {
    pub fn queen_moves(&self, queen_coord: (u8, Coord)) -> SquareIterator {
        SquareIterator::new(queen_coord.1, (0, 1), self.board_size(), |coord| {
            self.squares[coord.1][coord.0] == sv::EMPTY
        })
    }
}
```

After fiddling for two hours, reading up the lifetimes chapter in the rust book a couple of times, looking at the above mentioned other stackoverflow question, I am still at a loss as to how to teach Rust, that my closure will be alive as long as the iterator...

While I am aware, that there is lifetime stuff missing, the current ccode yields the error:

```
> error[E0310]: the parameter type `P` may not live long enough
  --> amazons-engine/src/lib.rs:33:18
   |
33 |       predicate: Box::new(predicate),
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `P` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...
   |
29 |     P: Fn(Coord) -> bool + 'static, {
   |                          +++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0310`.
```

So, how to do it?

Comment: Please always include the full error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that `SquareIterator` might be bound to a specific lifetime.  Closures that borrow from their environment aren't `'static`, but a struct without a lifetime parameter is assumed to reference nothing (e.g. be `'static`) itself.  This makes your closure that borrows `self` incompatible with the implied-static lifetime.

Step one is to tell the compiler that `SquareIterator` might refer to an external lifetime, and that this lifetime belongs to the closure type:

```
pub struct SquareIterator<'a> {
    upper_bounds: Coord,
    direction: Coord,
    predicate: Box<dyn 'a + Fn(Coord) -> bool>,
    current: Coord,
}
```

Step two is to adjust the constructor function similarly, which binds together the lifetime of the supplied closure with that of the returned `SquareIterator`, allowing the compiler to infer `'a` for you:

```
impl SquareIterator<'_> {
    pub fn new<'a, P>(
        start_square: Coord,
        direction: Coord,
        board_size: Coord,
        predicate: P,
    ) -> SquareIterator<'a>
    where
        P: 'a + Fn(Coord) -> bool,
    { ... }
}
```

Finally, the `impl Iterator` block needs to include a lifetime, but we can use the "please infer me" lifetime `'_` since the implementation doesn't depend on it:

```
impl Iterator for SquareIterator<'_> { ... }
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0e03d0425b2fca7a8bf51760174fd066), which has some placeholder types/methods to allow it to compile.)

Comment: magic! :) Thanks a lot - It looks like I expected, but I am not solid with the syntax of it all yet.

Comment: @BitTickler The bit that took me awhile of reading and experimenting to get is what the compiler means by "the type `P` doesn't live long enough." I had no idea what this meant at first (surely types live for the whole program!?). Eventually it dawned on me that bounding a generic type with a lifetime tells the compiler "if this type contains references, they must be valid for this lifetime."  This is why you often see bounds like `T: 'static` which means "if this type contains references, they have to be `'static`" -- but it _doesn't mean the type must contain references!_

Comment: @BitTickler So if you say `T: 'a` then that means the type's contained references must be valid for `'a`, but just as with `'static`, the type could also contain no references and satisfy the bound. A value that doesn't contain any references, or only `'static` references, will satisfy any lifetime bound.

Comment: And all the mention about references was a major point of confusion for me, both in the chapters of the rust book as well as in the error message. I do not pass the closure as reference (no `&`) and so it was totally unclear to me, where to place the lifetime information syntactically. With strong c++ background, I tend to fall into the trap to think about `&` in terms of references - where in Rust it is about borrowing.

Comment: @BitTickler Yeah, it can be a bit weird at first. Generally, any time you see a closure (`||`) there could be borrowing. Confusingly, there could even be borrowing if the closure is `move`. With C++ you can specify exactly what you capture by reference and by copy/move. With Rust you pick one or the other, so the way you do both is to capture references by move. `let x = ...; let y = ...; let z = &x; let c = move || y + z;`. This moves `y` and `z` into the closure, but `z` is a reference to `x` so this effectively captures `y` by move and `x` by reference.

Comment: @BitTickler To be a honest I wish Rust required you to list what you capture like C++ does. Admittedly this makes the syntax less pleasant, but removes a lot of the detective work required to figure out what a closure is capturing.